# Not returning proper output when cookie is set in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to setup an age verification box for a website in WordPress. I am using jQuery Cookie to set the cookie when the button is clicked. jQuery hides the box once it is clicked and then if the cookie is already set it shouldn't display the age verification box on subsequent pages. I tested this on another site which works without issue but on the current site it only works when logged in as an admin. Normal users see the box on every page, even though I have verified in Firebug that the cookie is set. Any ideas?

Here is how I am checking for the cookie on the page:

```
<?php if( !isset( $_COOKIE['consenting_age'] ) ) { ?>

    <div>Age Verification Box Here</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Here is a link to the site in question http://cutlersartisan.wpengine.com/distilery/

Comment: Hmmm... the code looks ok to me and I can see that the cookie has been set.  Peculiar.  Maybe the code isn't being run in the version you're running?

Comment: That makes me feel better. Well, sort of! It must be something conflicting in the theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the caching that wpengine has implemented see [Cookies and PHP Sessions](http://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/) and not the following

Looking at your site the problem is not in the php code but where you set the cookie value

```
    $j.cookie('consenting_age', 'yes', { expires: 30, path: '/', domain: '.cutlersartisan.wpengine.com' });
```

your domain name has a . at the front

try

```
    $j.cookie('consenting_age', 'yes', { expires: 30, path: '/', domain: 'cutlersartisan.wpengine.com' });
```

or leave out the domain completely

```
    $j.cookie('consenting_age', 'yes', { expires: 30, path: '/'});
```

Comment: I started without the domain at all but I tried adding the domain as a last stitch effort. I just removed it again to no effect. It works on another site I tested it on for both admins and users but the current site it only works for admins. Any other ideas?

Comment: http://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/
It seems like wpengine uses caching which might be breaking your cookies

Comment: Wow that makes perfect sense. That would explain why it's works for admins because the caching is turned off for admins. The other sites I tested it on were not running on WPEngine. I will open a ticket and check it out with them. I will let you know if that does the trick!

Comment: you were totally right. When using WPEngine you have to ask them to manually exempt whatever cookies you set otherwise the caching they use will essentially render an empty string and make it look like the cookie wasn't set. Two minutes on live chat with WPE fixed the problem. You guys rock!